# Using Apache PDFBox 1.3.1 - Trying to scale down all images in PDF file

Tags: java, pdfbox, scaling

I am forced to use ver. 1.3.1 of Apache PDFBox.  I wish I could use ver 2.+ but can't.  Anyway, I am trying to scale down the images in some PDF files but am having trouble.  If I was using ver 2.+ I could as I understand it use the {PDPageContentStream_obj}.transform(...) method but that's not avail. to me.  Instead as I understand it, I need to apply the .concatenate2CTM(...) method.  I am trying that but not getting the anticipated results; my resulting .pdf files display their graphics unchanged in scale.  Need to do this to reduce file size to under 5 MB so it can be successfully sent through a gateway that would time out if the file was bigger.  Changing the gateway timeout is not an option, unfortunately.  My code currently looks like this:

```
private File compressFile2(File file) throws Exception {
    try {
        PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(file);
        List<PDPage> pdPages = doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
        Iterator<PDPage> iterPdPages = pdPages.iterator();

        while (iterPdPages.hasNext()) {
            PDPage page = iterPdPages.next();
            PDPageContentStream cs = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page, true, true);
            cs.saveGraphicsState();
            cs.concatenate2CTM(.5, 0, 0, .5, 0, 0);
            cs.saveGraphicsState();
        }
        doc.save(file.getAbsolutePath() + "_compressed");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }
    return new File(file.getAbsolutePath() + "_compressed");
}
```

Any ideas are appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: You are using a version which is 12 years old and also contains several security vulnerabilities... Don't want to be in your position ;-)
What about converting the whole page to an image and then embedding that into a fresh PDF? So you can't introduce new libraries but maybe new methods and classes? So another option is to look at the newer (working) PDFBox Code and let it inspire you...

Comment: Even if the code would work (there are several reasons it doesn't, one is that you're not closing cs), all it would do is to make the PDF optically smaller, but not smaller in file size.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Thanks.  Any suggestions for making scaling work?

Comment: Scaling would not solve your problem, the file size would still be similar (maybe slightly larger). A possible solution would be to replace large images with lossy compressed images but that would be quite some work, and also make the PDF look poor and nobody would be happy, and it would not work for PDFs where the cause for the size isn't the images.